# nested modal window handling issue using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem, I am training in frontend development and I am doing a practical learning job, but I have a serious problem: the windows do not work as expected. in reality when I click on the "add a photo" button on the home page, it opens a first modal window in which there is a link which opens the second window and a close button which allows me to close the window. this close button works well when we have not opened the second window and when I click on the link to open window two I can no longer return to window one and when I click on the close button of window two it brings me back to window one and there comes the problem the first window can no longer close

this is the index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sophie Bluel - Architecte d'intérieur</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Syne:wght@700;800&family=Work+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">   
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Sophie Bluel <span>Architecte d'intérieur</span></h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="nav_menu projects"><a href="#portfolio">projets</a></li>
                <li class="nav_menu contact"><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
                <li class="nav_menu login"><a href="pages/login.html">login</a></li>
                <li class="nav_menu logout_hidden"><a href="index.html">logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="./assets/icons/instagram.png" alt="Instagram"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section id="introduction">
            <figure>
                <img src="./assets/images/sophie-bluel.png" alt="">
            </figure>
            <article>
                <h2>Designer d'espace</h2>
                <p>Je raconte votre histoire, je valorise vos idées. Je vous accompagne de la conception à la livraison finale du chantier.</p>
                <p>Chaque projet sera étudié en commun, de façon à mettre en valeur les volumes, les matières et les couleurs dans le respect de l’esprit des lieux et le choix adapté des matériaux. Le suivi du chantier sera assuré dans le souci du détail, le respect du planning et du budget.</p>
                <p>En cas de besoin, une équipe pluridisciplinaire peut-être constituée : architecte DPLG, décorateur(trice)</p>
            </article>
        </section>
        <section id="portfolio">
            <div class="edit_project">
                <h2>Mes Projets</h2>
                <div class="popup_edit">
                    <a href="#modal1" class="js-modal modify_action modify_hidden"><i class="fa-xs fa-solid fa-edit"></i> modifier</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation">
                <a href="#" class="active nav_link tous">Tous</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav_link objets">Objets</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav_link appartements">Appartements</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav_link hotels_restaurants">Hôtels&restaurants</a>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="contact">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <p>Vous avez un projet ? Discutons-en !</p>
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <label for="name">Nom</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Envoyer">
            </form>
        </section>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Mentions Légales</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>

    <aside id="modal1" class="modal" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="titlemodal" style="display:none;">
        <div class="modal-wrapper js-modal-stop">
            <div class="wrapper-nav">
                <a href="#" class="js-modal-close closed"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-content">
                <div class="content-title modal1-title">
                    <h2>Galerie photo</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal_gallery">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr><br>
            <div class="wrapper-link">
                <a href="pages/modal/modal2.html#modal2" class="js-modal modal_submit">Ajouter une photo</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/modal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the code for the second modal window:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Sophie Bluel - Architecte d'intérieur</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <aside id="modal2" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="titlemodal">
        <div class="modal-wrapper js-modal-stop">
            <div class="wrapper-nav">
                <a href="../../FrontEnd/index.html#modal1" class="js-modal"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left arow-link"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="js-modal-close"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-content">
                <div class="content-title">
                    <h2>Ajout photo</h2>
                </div>
                <div id="notification"></div>
                <form action="#" method="post" class="form-img">
                    <div class="container-load">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-light fa-image logo-load"></i>
                        <input type="file" id="imageUpload" name="imageUpload" accept=".jpg, .png" class="input-file">
                        <label for="imageUpload" class="input-label">+ Ajouter photo</label>
                        <p class="file-types">jpg, png : 4mo max</p>
                    </div>
                    <label for="name">Titre</label>
                    <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
                    <label for="email">Catégorie</label>
                    <input type="text" name="category" id="category">
                    <hr>
                    <input type="submit" value="Valider" >
                </form>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>    
    <script src="../../assets/js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/modal.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/modal_insert.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the js code of modale:

```
const focusableSelector = 'button, a, input, textarea'
let modal = null
let focusables = []
let previouslyFocusedElement = null

const openModal = async function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const target = e.target.getAttribute('href')
    if (target.startsWith('#')) {
        modal = document.querySelector(target)
    } else {
        modal = await loadModal(target)
    }
    focusables = Array.from(modal.querySelectorAll(focusableSelector))
    previouslyFocusedElement = document.querySelector(':focus')
    modal.style.display = null
    focusables[0].focus()
    modal.removeAttribute('aria-hidden')
    modal.setAttribute('aria-modal', 'true')
    modal.addEventListener('click', closeModal)
    modal.querySelector('.js-modal-close').addEventListener('click', closeModal)
    modal.querySelector('.js-modal-stop').addEventListener('click', stopPropagation)
}

const closeModal = function (e) {
    if (modal === null) return 
    if (previouslyFocusedElement !== null) previouslyFocusedElement.focus()
    e.preventDefault()
    /* Animation-direction reversed
    modal.style.display = "none"
    modal.offsetWidth
    modal.style.display = null
     */
    modal.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true')
    modal.removeAttribute('aria-modal')
    modal.removeEventListener('click', closeModal)
    modal.querySelector('.js-modal-close').removeEventListener('click', closeModal)
    modal.querySelector('.js-modal-stop').removeEventListener('click', stopPropagation)
    const hideModal = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none"
        modal.removeEventListener('animationend', hideModal)
        modal = null
    }
    modal.addEventListener('animationend', hideModal)
}

/*document.querySelector('.modal_submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('modal1').style.display = 'none';
});
*/
document.querySelector('.js-modal').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    document.getElementById('modal1').style.display = 'block';
});

const stopPropagation = function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
}

const focusInModal = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let index = focusables.findIndex(f => f === modal.querySelector(':focus'))
    if (e.shiftKey === true) {
        index--
    } else {
        index++
    }
    if (index >= focusables.length) {
        index = 0
    }
    if (index < 0) {
        index = focusables.length - 1
    }
    focusables[index].focus()
}

const loadModal = async function (url) {
    // TODO : Afficher un loader
    const target = '#' + url.split('#')[1]
    const exitingModal = document.querySelector(target)
    if (exitingModal !== null) return exitingModal
    const html = await fetch(url).then(response => response.text())
    const element = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(html).querySelector(target)
    if (element === null) throw `L'élément ${target} n'a pas été trouvé dans la page ${url}`
    document.body.append(element)
    return element
}

document.querySelectorAll('.js-modal').forEach(a => {
    a.addEventListener('click', openModal)
})

window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.key === "Escape" || e.key === "Esc") {
        closeModal(e)
    }
    if (e.key === 'Tab' && modal !== null) {
        focusInModal(e)
    }
})
```

to execute this it is very important that the server is launched, so I put the code on github in order to have a history and here is the link: https://github.com/amoungui/portfolio-architecte-sophie-blue